# How to extract data from an embed Raphael dataset to CSV?

Tags: csv, raphael

Attempting to extract the data from this [Google Politics Insights](http://gpolinsights.appspot.com/?hl=en&ed=us) webpage from "Jan-2012 to the Present" for Mitt Romney and Barack Obama for the following datasets:

- **Search Trends** Based on volume
- **Google News Mentions** Mentions in articles and blog posts
- **YouTube Video Views** Views from candidate channels

For visual example, here's what I mean:

[image]

Using Firebug I was able to figure out the data is stored in a format readable by Raphael 2.1.0; looked at the dataset and nothing strikes me as a simple way to convert the data to CSV.

**How do I convert the data per chart per presidential candidate into a CSV that has a table for "Search Trends", "Google News Mentions", and "YouTube Video Views" broken down by the smallest increment of time with the results measured in the graph are set to a value of "0.0 to 1.0"?** (Note: The reason for "0.0 to 1.0" is the graphs do not appear to give volume info, so the volume is relative to the height of the graph itself.)

Alternatively, if there's another source for all three datasets in CSV, that would work too.

Comment: As one could only guess, in what relation [**these values**](http://www.google.com/elections/data/trends/us/?hl=en&callback=jQuery172033727501635439694_1345014317767&_=1345014317916) are, the chances are odd to make it very readable. But I found out that they do `Math.log(dataPoints[i][j] * 100.0) / Math.log(logScaleBase);` in the `main.js (line 392)`. So it seems the logarithmus isn't already calculated into the data. Maybe this helps, otherwise you may find some other sources elsewhere.

Comment: @Dan Lee: Thank you, feel free to post your comment as an answer as it was of use to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I did that :). You can edit the reply to give more information of what you found out, if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to find out where the data comes from, so I looked up the network traffic in my developer console, and found it very soon: [**The data is stored as json here**](http://www.google.com/elections/data/trends/us/?hl=en&callback=jQuery172033727501635439694_1345014317767&_=1345014317916).

Now you've got plenty of data for each candidate. I don't know exactly in what relation these numbers are but they definitely are used for their calulation in the graph. I found out that the position in the [`main.js`](http://gpolinsights.appspot.com/static/js/main.js) is on line 392 where they calculate the data with this expression:

```
Math.log(dataPoints[i][j] * 100.0) / Math.log(logScaleBase);
```

My guess is: Without the logarithm and a bit exponential calculation you should get the right results.