# How to create a standalone SVG from a Raphael SVG?

Tags: svg

Attempting to [extract data embed in Raphael SVGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954091/how-to-extract-data-from-an-embed-raphael-dataset-to-csv), and hacking my way through options to get to the data. Currently, I've found what appears to be the SVG file with the data (this based on using Firebug and watch the data-swaps as the timeline changes) -- and attempting to convert the SVG into a [stand alone SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_example.asp) to confirm that at least visually the file appear to be the graph I'm looking at.

Here's the Raphael SVGs (or at least an SVG I'm not able to dump into an SVG template file I'm using and load without error):

```
<svg height="67" version="1.1" width="840" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<desc>Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
<defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="840" height="67" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ebebeb" stroke="none" style="">
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,1.5L67,1.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1">
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,3.5L67,3.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1">
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,7.5L67,7.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1">
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,15.5L67,15.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1">
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,32.5L67,32.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1">
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="#aaaaaa" stroke="none" d="M0,67L0,0L0,31L2.310344827586207,34L4.620689655172414,35L6.931034482758621,38L9.241379310344827,39L11.551724137931034,41L13.862068965517242,41L16.17241379310345,41L18.482758620689655,37L20.79310344827586,39L23.103448275862068,40L25.413793103448274,41L27.724137931034484,41L30.03448275862069,45L32.3448275862069,45L34.6551724137931,44L36.96551724137931,41L39.275862068965516,41L41.58620689655172,43L43.89655172413793,43L46.206896551724135,44L48.51724137931034,44L50.82758620689655,41L53.137931034482754,34L55.44...2068965517241,17L785.5172413793103,16L787.8275862068965,17L790.1379310344828,21L792.448275862069,22L794.7586206896551,23L797.0689655172414,21L799.3793103448276,20L801.6896551724137,17L804,12L806.3103448275862,15L808.6206896551724,16L810.9310344827586,17L813.2413793103448,15L815.551724137931,16L817.8620689655172,17L820.1724137931035,17L822.4827586206897,18L824.7931034482758,19L827.1034482758621,19L829.4137931034483,17L831.7241379310344,16L834.0344827586207,16L836.3448275862069,17L838.6551724137931,2L840,67" stroke-width="0" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-554.3785,0)">
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M0,31L2.310344827586207,34L4.620689655172414,35L6.931034482758621,38L9.241379310344827,39L11.551724137931034,41L13.862068965517242,41L16.17241379310345,41L18.482758620689655,37L20.79310344827586,39L23.103448275862068,40L25.413793103448274,41L27.724137931034484,41L30.03448275862069,45L32.3448275862069,45L34.6551724137931,44L36.96551724137931,41L39.275862068965516,41L41.58620689655172,43L43.89655172413793,43L46.206896551724135,44L48.51724137931034,44L50.82758620689655,41L53.137931034482754,34L55.44827586206...17L783.2068965517241,17L785.5172413793103,16L787.8275862068965,17L790.1379310344828,21L792.448275862069,22L794.7586206896551,23L797.0689655172414,21L799.3793103448276,20L801.6896551724137,17L804,12L806.3103448275862,15L808.6206896551724,16L810.9310344827586,17L813.2413793103448,15L815.551724137931,16L817.8620689655172,17L820.1724137931035,17L822.4827586206897,18L824.7931034482758,19L827.1034482758621,19L829.4137931034483,17L831.7241379310344,16L834.0344827586207,16L836.3448275862069,17L838.6551724137931,2" stroke-width="2" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-554.3785,0)">
</svg>
```

**How do I edit the SVG above to load as a standalone SVG file in the most recent version of FireFox?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Firefox shows two problems:

- the `ë` inside the `<desc>` tag is not a valid character. Remove the character or the whole `<desc>`.
- most of the used tags ( `<defs>`, `<rect>`, `<path>` ) are not closed. Just change the `>` at the end to `/>`.

I doubt, however, that this SVG shows your desired result.

```
<svg height="67" version="1.1" width="840" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<defs />
<rect x="0" y="0" width="840" height="67" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ebebeb" stroke="none" style="" />
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,1.5L67,1.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" />
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,3.5L67,3.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" />
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,7.5L67,7.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" />
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,15.5L67,15.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" />
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M0,32.5L67,32.5Z" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" />
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="#aaaaaa" stroke="none" d="M0,67L0,0L0,31L2.310344827586207,34L4.620689655172414,35L6.931034482758621,38L9.241379310344827,39L11.551724137931034,41L13.862068965517242,41L16.17241379310345,41L18.482758620689655,37L20.79310344827586,39L23.103448275862068,40L25.413793103448274,41L27.724137931034484,41L30.03448275862069,45L32.3448275862069,45L34.6551724137931,44L36.96551724137931,41L39.275862068965516,41L41.58620689655172,43L43.89655172413793,43L46.206896551724135,44L48.51724137931034,44L50.82758620689655,41L53.137931034482754,34L55.44...2068965517241,17L785.5172413793103,16L787.8275862068965,17L790.1379310344828,21L792.448275862069,22L794.7586206896551,23L797.0689655172414,21L799.3793103448276,20L801.6896551724137,17L804,12L806.3103448275862,15L808.6206896551724,16L810.9310344827586,17L813.2413793103448,15L815.551724137931,16L817.8620689655172,17L820.1724137931035,17L822.4827586206897,18L824.7931034482758,19L827.1034482758621,19L829.4137931034483,17L831.7241379310344,16L834.0344827586207,16L836.3448275862069,17L838.6551724137931,2L840,67" stroke-width="0" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-554.3785,0)" />
<path style="opacity: 1;" fill="none" stroke="#666666" d="M0,31L2.310344827586207,34L4.620689655172414,35L6.931034482758621,38L9.241379310344827,39L11.551724137931034,41L13.862068965517242,41L16.17241379310345,41L18.482758620689655,37L20.79310344827586,39L23.103448275862068,40L25.413793103448274,41L27.724137931034484,41L30.03448275862069,45L32.3448275862069,45L34.6551724137931,44L36.96551724137931,41L39.275862068965516,41L41.58620689655172,43L43.89655172413793,43L46.206896551724135,44L48.51724137931034,44L50.82758620689655,41L53.137931034482754,34L55.44827586206...17L783.2068965517241,17L785.5172413793103,16L787.8275862068965,17L790.1379310344828,21L792.448275862069,22L794.7586206896551,23L797.0689655172414,21L799.3793103448276,20L801.6896551724137,17L804,12L806.3103448275862,15L808.6206896551724,16L810.9310344827586,17L813.2413793103448,15L815.551724137931,16L817.8620689655172,17L820.1724137931035,17L822.4827586206897,18L824.7931034482758,19L827.1034482758621,19L829.4137931034483,17L831.7241379310344,16L834.0344827586207,16L836.3448275862069,17L838.6551724137931,2" stroke-width="2" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-554.3785,0)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Great, thanks that was a huge help in tracking down the data. So, you're correct, turns out that SVG was just display container for the data, [the data was in a DOM element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11956324/471255).